# How to bind image icon on ToolbarItem on Platform tag

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-toolbar

How to bind an image icon on the `ToolbarItem` OnPlatform tag in Xamarin.Forms

This is my code:

```
<ToolbarItem 
    Icon="{OnPlatform iOS='iconscalendarplus64.png', Android='iconscalendarplus64.png'}" 
    Priority="0"
    Order="Primary" 
    Command="{Binding PrikaziCommand}"
```

I am trying to bind images for the Android OnPlatform, but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the [`Android`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.onplatform-1.android?view=xamarin-forms) and `iOS` properties of the `OnPlatform` are not [`BindableProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.onplatform-1.android?view=xamarin-forms)

They don't support Data Binding. Hence you cannot bind those Property.

As an alternative you can set the platform specific image source to a property in the ViewModel and you it instead.

**XAML**

```cs
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="{Binding PlatformSpecificImage}"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

**View Model**

```cs
public ImageSource PlatformSpecificImage { get; set; }

public ViewModel()
{
    if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
    {
        PlatformSpecificImage = "android_image.png";
    }
    else
    {
        PlatformSpecificImage = "iOS_image.png";
    }
}
```

Hope this could help!

Comment: Thank you its helpfull information that OnPlatform are not BindableProperty.I try and see that is sometnihg wrong...I success with your help.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be something like :

```
                <ToolbarItem.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource">
                    <OnPlatform.iOS><FileImageSource File=""icon.png""/></OnPlatform.iOS>
                    <OnPlatform.Android><FileImageSource File=""icon.png""/></OnPlatform.Android>
                    <OnPlatform.WinPhone><FileImageSource File=""Images/icon.png""/></OnPlatform.WinPhone>
                </OnPlatform>
                </ToolbarItem.Icon>
```

The good thing is you can use all 4 types of ImageSource here based on platforms.

Good luck feel free to get back if you have queries

Comment: I try to implement this,and bindible File but dont work.I Bind property type string dont work,and try property ImageSource still dont see image on the screen.What can be?

Comment: Can you tell me where do you get this image from? is this in your native resources or is it coming from some API
 as a base 64 image?

Comment: I was trying to apply Platform specific icon to tab bar in Xamarin iOS and this helped me. Thanks....

Comment: @Thush-Fdo Happy to help!